# Is there a proof that the degree of the map $f: S^1 \to S^1$ given by $f(z) = z^n$ is $n$ which doesn’t use homology?

Tags: differential-topology

This was a proposed exercise in some lecture notes on differential topology I’m reading. Some proofs for this result are given [in the answers to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138398/how-to-calculate-rigorously-the-degree-of-the-map-f-s1-to-s1-fz-zn). However, they assume previous knowledge of algebraic topology, which the lecture notes don’t. That’s why I was curious to know if there’s an alternative proof.

The definition of degree of a map I’m using is the following: Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a smooth map between two oriented manifolds of the same dimension. Let $y\in Y$. Then $\deg_y(f)=I(f,\{y\})$, where $I(f,\{y\})$ is the intersection number of $f$ with $\{y\}$. If we also have that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a finite set $\forall y \in Y$ and that $Y$ is a connected manifold, then we define $\deg(f)=\deg_y(f)$ for any $y \in Y$.

I know as well that if $f,g:X \rightarrow Y$ are smooth maps such that $X$ is a compact manifold, $Y$ is a connected manifold and $f$ is homotopic to $g$, then $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$. I was thinking we could maybe use this in addition to the fact that the map $z\rightarrow z^n$ is homotopic to the identity map concatenated with itself $n$ times to prove that $\deg(f)=n$ (where $f: S^1 \to S^1$ is such that $f(z) = z^n$)?

Comment: Not only is the map $z \mapsto z^n$ *homotopic to* the identity map concatenated with itself $n$ times, but those two maps are *the same map*.

Comment: It seems to me that you can apply your definition directly: starting with the map $f(z)=z^n$; use $y=1 + 0i \in S^2$; compute $f^{-1}(y)$ to be $n$ equally spaced points around $S^1$ (the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity); and compute each of those individual points to have intersection number $1$, hence $I(f,\{y\}) = n \cdot 1 = n$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you! Then, I must see that for every root of unity $x \in f^{-1}(y)$, the orientation of $df_x (T_x S^1) \bigoplus T_{f(x)}\{y\}$ matches the orientation of $T_{f(x)}{S^1}$?

Comment: What you wrote looks a little garbled: You must show that the $df_x$-image of the given orientation on $T_x S^1$, which is an orientation on $df_x(T_x S^1) = T_{f(x)}(S^1) = T_y(S^1)$, matches the given orientation on $T_y S^1$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you! I was just trying to use the definition of intersection number as a sum of orientation numbers that was given in the lecture notes (which also appears [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2016/REUPapers/Mitsutani.pdf) for instance, page 7). But it must be equivalent to the one you mentioned.

Comment: is there perhaps a way to use riemann surfaces here? @LeeMosher afaik $S^2$ is riemann surface and then...hmmm...this is $S^1$ though. but anyway great question. homology. come on. kinda forgot about degree for smooth (i last learned degree for riemann surfaces), but i kinda remember homology doesn't sound natural to answer this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll turn my comments into an answer.

You can apply the definition of degree directly. Starting with the map $f(z)=z^n$, and using $y = 1 + 0i \in S^1$, the set $f^{-1}(y)$ consists of $n$ equally spaced points around $S^1$, namely the $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity, $x = \exp(2 \pi i k/n)$, $k=0,...,n-1$.

So, for each $x \in f^{-1}(y)$, you just have to prove that the local degree of $f$ at $x$ is equal to $+1$, because then the global degree is $I(f,\{y\}) = n \cdot 1 = n$. In fact it's just as easy to ignore the special value $y=1+0i$, and prove this local degree fact for all $x \in S^1$ and $y=f(x) \in S^1$.

What this local degree computation comes down to is to prove that the map
$$df_x : T_x S^1 \to T_{f(x)}S^1 = T_y S^1
$$
takes the standard orientation on $T_x S^1$ to the standard orientation on $T_y S^1$.